# Jest how to check async response

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and React so this should be a very simple question to answer...  I have an api-endpoint I'd like to check that I can hit.  I picked Axios as a client to try this and created the following test:

```
describe('Api Tests', () => {
  it('can perform an axios request', () => {
    console.log('Here goes!');

    const resp = axios.get('api-endpoint');
    console.log(resp);
    expect(resp).toBeDefined();

    console.log('Done...');
  });
});
```

Thankfully, the test passes, but with the following output:

```
 PASS  src\api\api.test.js
  Api Tests
    √ can perform an axios request (39ms)

  console.log src\api\api.test.js:15
    Here goes!

  console.log src\api\api.test.js:23
    Promise { <pending> }

  console.log src\api\api.test.js:25
    Done...
```

How do I test a simple request (WITHOUT MOCKING) so that I can get back a response that I can then interrogate?

Comment: make actual api call in test db. and verify that change in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `axios.get` returns a promise you should instruct [Jest to wait for the response](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) to return.

```
it('can perform an axios request', async () => {
  const resp = await axios.get('api-endpoint');
  expect(resp).toBeDefined();
});
```

or without `async` functions:

```
it('can perform an axios request', () => {
  return expect(axios.get('api-endpoint')).resolves.toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for... I didn't consider that the test itself was an anonymous method that could be defined as async.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have nice and easy method , maybe you will like it too. Just keep it simple.

```
`import axios from 'axios'; 
  axios.get('url goes here')
  .then(response =>{console.log(response)})`
```

Maybe find helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, I have already tried this, but it doesn't complete and show the promise.

Comment: try make a variable in state and store the full response there.